# What is the complete list of privileges a role needs in order to create a table in a schema?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have granted USAGE on the schemas and database.
I have granted select on all tables.

Using that role, I can read data from all tables within any schema.

I then grant the permission to create tables in all schemas within that database

```
GRANT CREATE TABLE ON ALL SCHEMAS IN DATABASE TEST1_CONTROL TO DEVELOPERS;
```

Yet, when I issue this command (while using DEVELOPERS role), I get an error

```
CREATE TABLE PDS.ERIC_TEST_TABLE(COUCOU STRING NULL);
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Did the schema PDS exist when `GRANT CREATE TABLE ON ALL SCHEMAS IN DATABASE TEST1_CONTROL TO DEVELOPERS;` was issued?

Comment: There is a chance schema PDS was created later. `SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE DEVELOPERS`

Comment: Yes, the schema did exist before.

In fact I seem to have cured this specific problem by issuing

grant create table on schema PDS to DEVELOPERS;

Weird...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me (script below).  Going to go with what Lukasz commented and that your schema was created later.

```
use role accountadmin;
create database TEST1_CONTROL;
create schema PDS;
create role DEVELOPERS;
grant role DEVELOPERS to user <your_username>;
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE TEST1_CONTROL TO DEVELOPERS;
GRANT USAGE ON ALL SCHEMAS IN DATABASE TEST1_CONTROL TO DEVELOPERS;
GRANT CREATE TABLE ON ALL SCHEMAS IN DATABASE TEST1_CONTROL TO DEVELOPERS;
use role DEVELOPERS;
CREATE TABLE PDS.ERIC_TEST_TABLE(COUCOU STRING NULL);
```

Snowflake does offer **future** grants if you want a role to have access to any new schemas that would be created in the future.

Comment: I don't know what to say... The schema did exist before my 

"GRANT CREATE TABLE ON ALL SCHEMAS IN DATABASE TEST1_CONTROL TO DEVELOPERS;"

Yet it only started to work when I issued (later) a grant on that specific schema...

Comment: I just did a similar test with stored procedure permission and this time it worked as expected...

"GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE ON ALL SCHEMAS IN DATABASE TEST1_CONTROL TO DEVELOPERS;"

And I could create my stored procedure immediately, still in the PDS schema.

I have to assume I made some basic error...

Comment: Thanks for confirming, Eric. We can probably discount it as a weird one-off or like you said, user error.  Glad it's working now.